# xcode9 crash reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero

Tags: xcode9

[3036:64570] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero.

Comment: Hi..Did you find any solution? Facing same very issue :(

Comment: yes i found it.

Comment: Sandy, what is the solution? Please always post here for others to learn. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's different possible reasons for this to happen. I got this crash when I made a connection from a navigation bar item to an outlet or action (or both) from my storyboard to my code. I have to add a target and action from the code to prevent the crash from occurring.